# Create variable based on next observation in R

Tags: r

I think this should be simple but I can't get it. I am trying to create a variable based on whether or not the next variable is a "Goal". I have little experience with R, and don't really understand how to reference the next observation. I had a more complicated question answered earlier and it was helpful, but I think I just need a more basic understanding first.

My data looks like the input below:

```
event<-c("Pass","Goal","Pass","Pass","Pass","Pass","Goal")
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
event   assist
Pass      1
Goal      NA
Pass      NA
Pass      NA
Pass      NA
Pass      1
Goal      NA
```

Any explanation would be great. Thanks.

Comment: `library(dplyr);ifelse(lead(event == "Goal"), 1, NA)` or you can also get the indices of the 1 values by `which(event == "Goal") - 1`

Comment: Or `c(tail(event,-1),FALSE)=="Goal"` for another base R method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess if you want to understand the basics, there's no better way than to use base R

```
assist = rep(NA,length(event)) #create an empty assist vector
for (i in 1:length(event)-1){  #the loop goes over the entire length of event except the last
         if (event[i+1] == "Goal") #if the following element is "Goal"; the index is referencing the next observation
               {assist[i] = 1} #then do this
         else{assist[i] = NA} #else this
}
```

and you get the output:

```
> assist
[1]  1 NA NA NA NA  1 NA
```

But you should use either of the two methods mentioned in the comments. It's more elegant.

Comment: Thanks for this. This is exactly what I have been looking for. The commented sections are really helpful thank you.